# jpa save InetAddress without blob

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Is there a other way to save a `private InetAddress ip;` in a JPA entity then

- save it as a blob
- create a sub-class

Maybe a way with `@Type`? So that there is a readable entry in the database a human can also read/change.
(On UUID you for example have `@Type(type="uuid-char")` or with a enum you have `@Enumerated`, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JPA 2.1 standard `AttributeConverter`. That way you can be portable across all JPA providers, and can persist it as the type you want (String, Integer, etc).

Using Hibernate specific `Type` would be totally non-portable